# 'Unauthorized for query on _SCHEMA' for MongoDB only on Parse

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I have a migrated Parse application running on Parse 2.1.6. It uses a simple MongoDB 3.0.8 (RocksDB engine) setup, with authentication. The user it's using has the permissions:

```
[{ "role" : "dbAdmin", "db" : "parse" },
 { "role" : "readWrite", "db" : "parse"}]
```

When the Parse server boots up or tries to handle any request, I get:

```
[MongoError: not authorized for query on parse._SCHEMA]
```

Which seems very weird, given that:

- the user clearly *has* permissions to query any collection on this database,
- that same user is indeed able to query this collection via mongo console or robomongo,
- Parse.com works normally when using this database, with that same user,
- I can actually run the same Parse application locally, pointing to this same remote MongoDB with that user, and it works without such errors.

This is kinda crazy. I get the feeling that I'm missing something pretty basic here. Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
As request, sample code showing how the server is booting:

```
var api = new ParseServer({ appId: 'the app id',
  masterKey: 'the master key',
  clientKey: 'client key',
  cloud: '/absolute_path/cloud/main.js',
  serverURL: 'https://myserver.com/parse',
  push:
   { ios:
      { production: false,
        bundleId: 'thebundleid.com',
        pfx: <Buffer ... > } },
  oauth: { facebook: { appIds: 'appId' } },
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://user@pass:127.0.0.1:27017'
});
app.use('/parse', api);
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct **API Keys** Provide sample code snipet for a better understanding of the problem

Comment: Yes, I'm using the correct API keys - however, this is not very relevant given that what fails is the database connection, and before any request is handled.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Found any solution ??